# Iterated dimensional regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, regularization

Given a 2-loop divergent integral $\int F(q,p)\,\mathrm{d}p\mathrm{d}q$, can it be solved iteratively? I mean

1. I integrate over $p$ keeping $q$ constant
2. Then I integrate over $q$

In both iterated integrals I use dimensional regularization.

Can it be solved iteratively? I presented a paper to a teacher of mine about regularization of integrals using the Zeta regularization. He told me that for one dimensional integrals (or one loop integrals) it was fine, but that my method could not handle multi loop integrals. I argue back that you could apply the regularization method by introducing a regulator of the form

$$(a+qi)^{-s}$$

I could make the integral on each variable by iterated regularization, that is applying the algorithm iteratively.

EDIT: i think they have cheated me :) making up excuses not to put me atention

by the way , how can i insert math codes on my posts ?? is just setting `$` at the beginning and the end of the equation ??

---

### Edit: 19th of July

thanks :) your answer was quite useful :)

however can I not  insert a term $(qi+a)^{-s} $ on each variable and then apply the regularization iteratively ??

I say so because I made a paper http://vixra.org/abs/1009.0047 to regularize integrals using the regulator $(q+1)^{-1}$ and tried to extend it to several variables, however that was my doubt, if i could apply my regularization scheme to every variable :) thanks again

I mean for a one dimensional integral $\int dx (x+a)^{m-s}$, I know how to regularize it by using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula plus the Riemann Zeta function $ \zeta (s-m)$

Then for multiloop integrals, I had thought that i could introduce the $s$-regulators (x+a)^{-s}(y+a)^{-s}.. and so on on each variable, and then apply iterated integration... :)

so this is a resume of my method..

a) i know how to use Zeta regularization to get finite values for the integral $ \int dx(x+a)^{m-s} $ in terms of the Riemann Zeta function $ \zeta (s-k) $ with k=-1,0,1,....,m

b) for a more general 1-dimensional integral $ \int dx f(x)(x+a)^{-s}$ i add substract a Polynomial $K(x+a)(x+a)^{-s} $ to get a finite part and then regularize the divergent integrals  $dx(x+a)^{m-s} $

c) for a more complicate 2-loop integral $ \iint dpdq F(q,p)(p+a)^{-s}(q+a)^{-s} $ to obtain a regularization of it i do the sema method , first on 'p' considering 'q' a constant and i treat it as a one dimensional integral over 'p' and then over 'q' by substracting a Polynoamials $ K(q,p+a)(p+a)^{-s} $ and so on

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I can't really see why it wouldn't work. Hm. Good question.

Comment: What do You do with the partial results (first over p, then over q?). Add them? Multiply?

Comment: @wsc: I know it doesn't work and also that two (not to mention higher higher) loop diagrams can get *very* tricky (e.g. a friend of mine very recently published [a result on some two-loop radiative corrections](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5956) to $\pi^0 \to e^+ e^-$). But unfortunately that's all I know as this isn't my field.

Comment: Response to Jul19 edit: Of course you can apply your regularization like that. But remember that there's no canonical way of routing momentum through a Feynman diagram, so you regularized integral will be dependent on this arbitrary choice. This makes it more difficult (but not impossible) to get a consistent renormalization scheme. That is, to consistently subtract subdivergences so that you always have local counterterms. I also imagine that your regularization will break gauge invariance / Ward identites, which will need to be fixed with finite counterterms.

Comment: (Continued) Anyway, try to use your regularization to produce something like 2-loop propagator results in QED and see what happens. Can you always get local counterterms? What about the Ward identities?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the rants by Bonneau [[1](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/find/hep/www?irn=4452577)] [[2](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/find/hep/www?irn=2176750)] on regularization. Also some of the discussions in the implicit renormalization papers ([for example](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1377)).

Comment: Why do you use $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^{s}=\zeta (s)$ in your paper
(http://vixra.org/abs/1009.0047) instead of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}=\zeta (s)$ ?

Comment: @Américo: There's a few such typos in his paper.

Comment: it was a mistake,. as for the counterterms i do not need counterterms since ALL the integrals can be regularized to get FINITE answer in the same sense that you can get finite answers to 'Casimir effect' by zeta regularization $ \zeta(-3)=1/120 $ so my method does not need counterterms in the same sense that zeta egularization for series does not need counterterms.

Comment: @Jose: Even if it doesn't have counterterms (and that's not clear in your paper), you still need to make sure that subdivergences and overlapping divergences are treated properly. This is why I referred you to hep-th/9303044, where this issue is thoroughly discussed for differential renormalization - which also has no counterterms.

Comment: @Jose: That said, there are still counterterms, they're just not explicit. Your method tries to modify the ill defined product of distributions to get a well defined distribution. The difference between the two is the counterterm that you've subtracted. Essentially your method is defining a [R-operator](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bogoliubov-Parasiuk-Hepp-Zimmermann_renormalization_scheme) that needs to satisfy Bogoliubov's recursion or Zimmermann's forest formula.

Comment: but zeta regualrization has proved to respect all the physics , for example in casimir effect why would go wrong now ? anyway you get finte results if $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-1}= \gamma  $ and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{s}= \zeta (-s) $ ,could someone help me to publish my paper in any journal? i am not famous so they reject my papers so i would need someone tho publish it

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you can *actually do* the dimensionally regularized integrals, then yes, you can integrate iteratively. Normally, two-loop and higher-loop integrals are quite difficult and you need good tricks like turning them into differential equations or using Mellin-Barnes parametrization of the propagators (or even just Feynman or Schwinger parametrizations).
The new standard book on evaluating dimensionally regularized multiloop integrals is 
[Feynman Integral Calculus](http://books.google.com/books?id=uYW6raeFrCUC) by Vladimir Smirnov (2006). Also see the notes for the Father & Son [lectures at Durham](http://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/Workshops/08/FeynmanIntegrals) a couple of years ago.

Not only are multiloop integrals hard, but the regularization scheme becomes important once you leave one-loop. This is because you have to make a consistent renormalization / subtraction of counter-terms. Regularization schemes that modify the diagrams/integrals and not the original Lagrangian can lead to messy renormalization analysis. The simplest renormalization analyses are associated with regularizations that change the Lagrangian (or dimension) combined with a mass-independent minimal subtraction scheme.

Inserting terms like $(q^2)^s$ is a type of analytic regularization, which (like most regularizations) is easy at one-loop, but tricky at higher loops. Analytic regularization was extensively examined by [Eugene Speer](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~speer/homepage/publications.html) in the 60s and 70s.

Zeta regularization does only work at one-loop, but it has a generalization/extension called *Operator Regularization* that was [studied by McKeon and friends](http://inspirebeta.net/search?p=f%20a%20McKeon%20and%20t%20Operator%20Regularization). From memory, the calculations get a bit messy, although there is [a new(ish) paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1806) on using operator regularization and Feynman diagrams that is on my reading list  (previous work used a more Schwinger-like, functional approach to loop calculations).

---

I hope that something I said in the above is useful and not too much is wrong. ;)

Comment: i managed to obtain finite results for one dimensional and multi-dimensional integrals in my paper  http://vixra.org/abs/1009.0047 however they reject my saying it is WRONG but without giving any proof, they say that for one loop it may be okey but that it would not work on multi-loo`ps however i believe that by iterated integral i could apply zeta regularization to multiple integrals :( but since i can not get a grant i can not publish my papers

Comment: @Jose: Getting a finite result from a divergent integral is easy. Doing it in a sensible way and getting consistent physical results is hard. For example, your method breaks momentum routing invariance - not that that is necessarily fatal. Try reading [Consistency Conditions for 4-D Regularizations](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998MPLA...13.1597B) and the papers by Bonneau [[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0217751X90001641), [2](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0008210)] and the intro to [Breitenlohner, Maison](http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/BF01609069).

Comment: @Jose: A grant and a uni position is helpful for getting papers published, but not essential. Your paper might have some useful stuff in it, but it's not very clear. Try to really clarify what your new idea is and how it fits into the ecosystem of other regularizations. How does your generalization of zeta function regularization (if it is that) compare to that of McKeon et al? How does it work in the two-loop $\phi^4$ calculation? How about gauge invariance?

Comment: here it is explained with some examples i gave no renormalization so i do not know how to work for the $ \phi ^4 $ theory, however i have checked that for finite integrals the results are the same..for multi-loop or multiple integrals we can do iterated integration over one of each variable to get a regularization for them , by introducing the regulator $ (q+1)^{-s}$ we can make the integral convergent

Comment: why my method will not work ?? zeta regularization WORKS well for series why not for integrals :( , sorry i would like to know before giving up , why DImensional regularization works but not zeta regularization ? , why can not we make iterated integration over every variable and then apply my method of zeta regularization for integrals ?, why can not this method be applied to define the product of delta function with itself?, i think that my methdo would respect ALL the rules of calculus and that can be used to get finite correction for the UV divergences and IR divergences

Comment: @Jose: As I said - anyone can get a finite result from a divergent integral - the trick is doing it in a well defined or well controlled way. So stop *thinking* that your method works and start *showing* that it does. You might be right and your method is pure genius, but no one is going to take your word for it, you have to show them. Reproduce the basic QFT results. (Ultimately it would be nice to show that it's a consistent renormalization scheme and satisfies Zimmermann’s forest formula / Hopf algebra structure.)

Comment: @Jose: Also normal zeta fn reg of the 1-loop determinant does not introduce regularization parameters. Your multi-loop scheme does introduce such parameters - and in such a way as to break momentum routing invariance. Similar [analytic regularizations were considered by Speer](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Multiloop_Feynman_integrals#Regularization) - I read his work a long while back and from memory, it's not simple to make a consistent multi-loop analytic regularization scheme.

Comment: @Jose: As for the product of delta-fns; all regularization in QFT is a way of getting "sensible" results for products of distributions. The classic QFT example of this is differential renormalization by Freedman. See all of the excellent references in http://arxiv.org/refs/hep-th/9303044

Comment: What extra parameter do i introduce ?? i mean the divergent integrals can be defined in terms of the negative values of the Riemann Zeta function  $\zeta (-k)$ k=0,1,2,3,.... for the case of the logarithmic integral using the expansion of the Digamma function i get $\int dx (x+a)^{-1} $ = -loga so there is no extra parameter introduced.  For the case of multiple integrals i apply iteratively the method i developed for one variable , in the end if all the integrals are finite i do not know why my method won't work

Comment: @Jose: To quote your paper "Here we have introduced a regulator depending on an external parameter 's'". With a regularization using parameters you then have counterterms depending on those parameters that need to be subtracted. With a regularization/renormalization with out parameters you need to make sure the renormalization scheme properly treats the subdiagrams so that unitarity and locality are preserved.

Comment: @Jose: Differential renormalization, like zeta function renormalization, does not have regularizaton parameters. When it was first introduced it was demonstrated to be useful and old loop calculations and beta functions were reproduced.  In [hep-th/9303044](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9303044) it was given more solid ground. Please read this paper and understand the issues involved. **Getting a finite result is not enough.** You need to do it in a way that preserves the physics.

Comment: @Jose: Until you've shown that you've read the above paper and made some attempt to understand the issues involved with subtraction of subdivergences in multiloop calculations, I will not reply to any more comments. (Of course, your method might be the magic one that does not need to worry about such considerations. In which case show me by reproducing a nontrivial two-loop calculation)

Comment: could someone write me a 2-loop integral so i can upload a regularization for it to see you how my method works and gets finite result for divergent integrals ??.. thanks

Comment: @Jose: The simplest nontrivial two-loop integral is the vacuum sunset integral. You should be able to reproduce eqn(B.18) in [hep-th/0511004](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0511004) with the $\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}$ terms set to zero. You can also set all but one mass to zero to make things easier for you. Your result should match theirs up to a shift of the renormalization parameter $\bar\mu$. Also see the appendix in my [arXiv:0805.3574](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3574), where I have a similar result but without the subdivergences subtracted (thus the $L_2$ terms remain).

Comment: perhpas i can make a change of variable to POLAR COORDINATES and then integrate numerically over the angles , i have no other idea :( ,if i could make a change to polar variables and integrate over the angles then all the integrals would depend on the parameter 'r' anyway thanks for your comments

Comment: @Jose: Maybe the answer (and papers) I gave in your [zeta reg](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12533/429) question will be of more help.

Comment: can anyone help me to publsih my paper in a respectable journal D: so i can get a grant from one university and to apply my method of zeta regularization ?? thanks