# Why Zeta regularization is not valid for multiple-loops?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, renormalization

Why zeta regularization only valid at one-loop?

I mean there are zeta regularizations for multiple zeta sums.
Also we could use the zeta regularization iteratively on each variable 
to obtain finite corrections to multiple loop diagrams.

Comment: Possibly related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12235/2451

Answer (score 6):

The standard use of zeta-regularization in quantum field theory is to replace the ill defined one-loop functional determinant with something finite:

$$\begin{align} 
   \det(H) &= \exp(\mathrm{tr}\log H) := \exp(-\zeta'_H(0))\,, \\
   \zeta_H(s) &= \mathrm{tr} H^{-s} = \frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t\, t^{s-1}\mathrm{tr}(\exp(-H t))
\end{align}$$

This is a generalization of the 
Riemann zeta-function $\zeta(s)=\zeta(s,q)$ and 
[Hurwitz zeta-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) $\zeta(s,q)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (q+n)^{-s}$ 
since $$\zeta_H(s) = \mathrm{tr} H^{-s} = \sum_{n} \lambda_n^{-s}\,.$$ For example, for the harmonic oscillator, $\lambda_n=n+\frac12$ so $\zeta_H(s)=\zeta(s,\frac12)$.

This obviously only works at one-loop because the quantum corrections only look like a functional determinant at one-loop.

**But related ideas can be extended to multiple loops.** (How does the following compare to your scheme? It's hard to tell exactly what you're saying in [your paper](http://vixra.org/abs/1009.0047)...)

In [your previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12235/2451) I mentioned operator regularization (e.g. [PhysRevD.35.3854](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.35.3854)) as an extension of zeta-regularization.
Here, the functional determinant is written using 
$$\begin{align} 
   \det(H) &= \exp(\mathrm{tr}\log H) \\
 \log H &:= \lim_{s\to0}\Big[-\frac{d^m}{d s^m}\Big[\frac{s^{m-1}}{m!}H^{-s}\Big]\Big]\,,
\end{align}$$
for some large enough (only actually need $m=1$) integer $m$. With $m=1$ and writing $H^{-s}=\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}t\, t^{s-1}\exp(-H t)$ you recover the zeta-regularized form given above.

Similarly you can also regularize the propagators $H^{-1}$ as
$$    H^{-1} = \frac{d}{d H}\log H := \lim_{s\to0}\Big[\frac{d^m}{d s^m}\Big[\frac{s^{m}}{m!}H^{-s-1}\Big]\Big]\,.
$$
This is the underlying basics of operator regularization.

In [arXiv:1006.1806](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1806), this was generalized to 
$$    H^{-n} := \lim_{s\to0}\Big[\frac{d^m}{d s^m}\Big[
      \big(1+\alpha_1s+\dots+\alpha_ms^m\big)\frac{s^{m}}{m!}H^{-s-n}\Big]\Big]\,.
$$
where the $\alpha_i$ are initially arbitrary finite constants and $m$ is the loop order (or higher).
Comparisons were made with some dimensionally regularized Feynman integrals and it was found that for a choice of $\alpha_i$ they matched. 
These constants are fixed according the renormalization scheme that is used. I'm not sure if  a "minimal subtraction" scheme exists for operator regularization (unless you do a comparison with dimensional regularization for each diagram!) or if a physical/on-shell renormalization scheme has to be used to ensure consistent results.

A much more solid paper is [Operator regularization and multiloop Green's functions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.41.514).
There they define the subtraction operator (with out the $\alpha_i$ constants)
$$ \mathcal S^{(m)}\big(\prod_i A_i^{-1}\big) 
   = \lim_{s\to0}\frac{d^m}{d s^m}\Big[\frac{s^{m}}{m!}\Big(\prod_i A_i^{-s-1}\Big)\Big]
$$ 
and show that its naive application to obtain finite amplitudes breaks unitarity.
(The results of arXiv:1006.1806 suggest that if you include the $\alpha_i$'s and choose them correctly, you should be able to get correct results...)
Then they actually use Bogolibov's recursion formula to show how to construct a consistent $\mathcal R$-operator from $\mathcal S$.

Detail computations are given for both the naive and sophisticated use of operator regularization in massive $\phi^4_4$ theory.

Note that using a BPHZ-like scheme essentially reintroduces counterterms (hidden in the subtractions in each diagram) to the method and definitely breaks the simplicity of the original $\zeta$-regularization.

Comment: Note that all of this opens up the question of whether it's possible to use the approach of arXiv:1006.1806 consistently fix the constants using a MS-like scheme. I.e. If it's possible to get away with not applying physical renormalization conditions or BPHZ-like subtractions at each order...

Comment: However, why can not simply set the divergent terms to 0 , i mean if you have the sum of divergent quantities $ \sum a_{n} e^{-n} $ then this is divergent in the limit e-->0 then you simply 'ignore' this quantities and keep always the FINITE PART in the sense of zeta regularization $ \zeta (1)= \gamma$ and $ 1+2^{m}+3^{m}+.......................= \zeta (-m) $ so no counterterms are needed

Comment: @Jose: As I've been saying for days (!) in order to have unitary scattering amplitudes you need to be careful and consistent about how you renormalize the naively divergent Feynman integrals. The [final paper I linked to](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.41.514) has an example of what goes wrong if you're not careful.

Comment: @Jose: Read about [BPHZ renormalization](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bogoliubov-Parasiuk-Hepp-Zimmermann_renormalization_scheme) and the classic papers on how [analytic](http://www.springerlink.com/content/j56268puh6253393/), [dimensional](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01609069) and [differential renormalization](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9303044) are additive renormalizations and equivalent to BPHZ up to finite counterterms. Also interesting is the [Hopf algebra underlying renormalization](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/10/hopf_algebraic_renormalization.html).

Comment: @Jose: Also thanks for making me think about this stuff again. It's interesting and important material, but lacking in most modern text books. I still don't feel that I have a completely solid grasp on it. The "General remarks" section of the [scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bogoliubov-Parasiuk-Hepp-Zimmermann_renormalization_scheme) is an interesting read.

Comment: ok i get it my paper is wrong :) however i still hoped to define it or give it a definition to give a finite meaning for divergent integrals in mathematics in the same fashion you give finite results for divergent series in Zeta regularization :) , i hoped to get a grant for my ideas at my university but failed , i thought that once you got the correct maths results the physics results would be obvious :)

Comment: @Jose: Having and exploring a good idea is the important thing - and generalizing zeta-reg to higher loops is a good idea. And lots of people have got tripped up on regularization/renormalization. There's been many controversies about spurious anomalies because of such misunderstandings. See the couple of rants about this by Bonneau [[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0217751X90001641)] [[2](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0008210)].