# Not satisfied with "trick" in zeta function regularization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, regularization

I am not satisfied with the explanations of  $$\sum_n \log \lambda_n = - \frac{d}{ds} \sum_n \lambda_n^{-s}\bigg|_{s=0}$$ "trick" used in zeta function regularization, discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18106/zeta-function-regularization-in-qft-for-heat-kernels) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12533/why-zeta-regularization-is-not-valid-for-multiple-loops/13045#13045), or the references therein. If someone could give a step-by-step explanation or a reference if the explananation is more complicated than I'm guessing, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For fun, an other basic trick, used for entropy, is $S = - Tr(\rho \log \rho) = -\frac{d}{ds} Tr(\rho^s)_{|s=1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a function of $s$ as
$$
f(s) = \frac{1}{a^s}
$$
Now take the derivative with respect to $s$:
$$
f'(s)=\frac{d}{ds}a^{-s}=-\frac{\log(a)}{a^s}
$$
What happens at $s=0$?
$$
f'(s=0)=-\frac{\log(a)}{a^0}=-\log(a)
$$

What happens if $a=a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots$ (i.e., $s$-independent constants)? We simply stick in a sum:
$$
f(s) =\sum_n \frac{1}{a_n^s}
$$
What does this do to the final answer? Nothing, we still can stick in the sum:
$$
f'(s=0)=-\sum_n\frac{\log(a_n)}{a_n^0}=-\sum_n\log(a_n)
$$

Thus, we get our relation,
$$
\left.\frac{d}{ds}\sum_n\lambda_n^{-s}\right|_{s=0}=-\sum_n\log\left(\lambda_n\right)
$$